# Verify Metamask signature (ethereum) using Python

Tags: python, ethereum, digital-signature, ecdsa, metamask

I would like to verify an **ethereum** (ETH) **signature** made in MetaMask using **python**. I'm developing a website using flask as backend.
Javascript code send a POST requests to the back end containing the 3 following variables:

```
{'signature': '0x0293cc0d4eb416ca95349b7e63dc9d1c9a7aab4865b5cd6d6f2c36fb1dce12d34a05039aedf0bc64931a439def451bcf313abbcc72e9172f7fd51ecca30b41dd1b', 'nonce': '6875972781', 'adress': '0x3a806c439805d6e0fdd88a4c98682f86a7111789'}
```

My goal is to verify that the signature contains the **nonce (random integer)** and was sign by the **public adress**

I using javascript to sign the nonce  using the [ether library](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/apis/javascript/)

```
const ethereum = window.ethereum;
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(ethereum)
const signer = provider.getSigner()
var signature = await signer.signMessage(nonce);
```

I tried with several python libraires, but I'm unable to format signature, adress and nonce so that it works. here is unsuccessfull try made using ecdsa librairy:

```
vk = ecdsa.VerifyingKey.from_string(bytes.fromhex(address), curve=ecdsa.SECP256k1, hashfunc=sha256) 
vk.verify(bytes.fromhex(hex(signature)), bytes(nonce, 'utf-8'))
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 1
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Here is some Python signing and verifying code I did  back in a day https://github.com/TokenMarketNet/smart-contracts/blob/master/ico/sign.py

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using web3.py you could use w3.eth.account.recover_message to recover the address from the signature and the data. After that you compare the adress to the correct adress(with lowercase, because i think web3.py would give you lower and uppercase)

```
from web3 import Web3
from hexbytes import HexBytes
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(""))
mesage= encode_defunct(text="6875972781")
address = w3.eth.account.recover_message(mesage,signature=HexBytes("0x0293cc0d4eb416ca95349b7e63dc9d1c9a7aab4865b5cd6d6f2c36fb1dce12d34a05039aedf0bc64931a439def451bcf313abbcc72e9172f7fd51ecca30b41dd1b"))
print(address)
```

Comment: I use `encode_defunct` as well but I can't help thinking about what the method's description says, "Encode a message for signing, using an old, unrecommended approach.. Only use this method if you must have compatibility with
    :meth:`w3.eth.sign() <web3.eth.Eth.sign>`.". Do you know of any alternates?

Comment: that's because you use:
var signature = await signer.signMessage(nonce);

another option, i think is use in js
var signature = await signer._signTypedData from https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/

and then encode_structured_data from https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.messages.encode_intended_validator

in that case is not a string to sign, is a eip712 estructured data. But eip721 is not approved, and the two methods are experimentals.

Answer (score 2):

You can verify using JS but I commend you for wanting to verify on the backend with python. I was faced with the exact same choice and opted for the latter. Basically, I created 2 apis, the first of which generates the message and nonce and the second verifies the signature.

I'm using [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) for this but you can pattern it to any framework you prefer such as Django.

**Generate message:**

```py
# ethaccount is the user's wallet included in the body of the request
async def generate_message(ethaccount: str = Body(...)) -> str:
    # I save the wallet to cache for reference later
    set_cache_address(ethaccount)

    # Generate the nonce
    nonce = uuid.uuid4()

    # Generate the message
    message = f'''
Welcome! Sign this message to login to the site. This doesn't cost you
anything and is free of any gas fees.

Nonce:
{nonce}.
    '''
    return message
```

Metamask takes over from here. Afterwards **verify the signature generated by metamask:**

```py
from web3.auto import w3
from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct

async def signature(data: dict = Body(...)):     # noqa
    # User's signature from metamask passed through the body
    sig = data.get('signature')

    # The juicy bits. Here I try to verify the signature they sent.
    message = encode_defunct(text=data.get('message'))
    signed_address = (w3.eth.account.recover_message(message, signature=sig)).lower()

    # Same wallet address means same user. I use the cached address here.
    if get_cache_address() == signed_address:
        # Do what you will
        # You can generate the JSON access and refresh tokens here
        pass
```

NOTE: I've cleaned this code to show only the logic/methods you might need. The actual code I'm using is longer as I generate tokens, etc.

Comment: what's the (data: dict = Body(...))

Can i use request, and do i need to define a Body. about to run this code